# Helix terminology

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Consider the following helix:

[image]

Is there a mathematical term for the section highlighted in red?  Two that immediately spring to mind are "period" and "cycle".  However, my advisor (a differential geometer) seemed to think that a more specific term exists.

Comment: The vertical distance between the two end-points is called the _pitch_ of the helix. I don't know of any term for the highlighted curve itself; if I needed one, I might call it a _revolution_ of the helix.

Comment: *One pitch Coil segment ?*